# How to read a FileGDB using QGIS 2.18.7 /GDAL 2.1?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I have imported a gdb file into `PostGis` using `GDAL 2.1.3` and am facing the following issue :-

When I try to add the layer which is a multiline string to the canvas from the `QGIS DB Manager` I don't see anything in the QGIS canvas window. In the QGIS layers panel when I check number of features it shows zero. The attribute window is also empty (no rows) but the columns are populated. When I check in the properties window under fields, I do see a field which has a type `QString` and a type name as `Binary`.

> Field se_anno_cad_data ignored, because of unsupported type bytea

[image]

There also seems to be some data found in raster files as can be seen from the output of the `ogrinfo` command below :

[image]

How can I figure this out?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] which states there should be only one question per question.  Please [edit] your question to focus on only one specific question.

Comment: I have updated accordingly. Please let me know if something else/more is required.

Comment: To answer this question we need more information. For instance, how many rows does PostGIS show?  Is there an entry for this table in the Geometry or Geography columns view?  Can you open the original GDB in QGIS (change source type from the default 'File' to 'Directory') - note that you don't need to import to PostGIS first if you don't want to?

Comment: I have tried in my original post to indicate that the issue is with 2 fields - one of type `bytea` and the other is a spatialref of type `geometry (MultilineString, 4326)`. Since the recommendation was to fork out into 2 separate questions I did move out the 2nd field. I have updated the original post with some screenshots.

Comment: run this query and upload a pic of the results SELECT * FROM public.geometry_columns ORDER BY type

Comment: Here is a gist of the output with filter on the specific `f_table` in question -> https://gist.github.com/ZeroGraviti/bf0153646a26bdc0a835544febcdfa6b